# TravisCI can't use a long environment variable

Tags: tdd, travis-ci

I'm trying to add a environment variable on TravisCI like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

(It's not real key)

when I try to add, TravisCI undo my format text

[image: Travis can't use the enviroment variable]

How i can use a long enviroment vars on TravisCI?

Comment: See https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7715. In this particular case, you can concatenate all lines into a single line.

Answer (score 4):

I found on github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7715 this:

> 1.replace all EOL (line break) by `\n`
>   2. In the web interface, copy-paste the value with the following prefix "$(echo -e ' and suffix ')"
>
> For example, to export
>
> ```
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
> MKOQ1zYTmd
> zkRpTFq4xu
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
> ```
>
> replace EOL with \n and escape special characters such as space edit :
>   you don't need to escape other characters
>
> ```
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMKOQ1zYTmd\nzkRpTFq4xu\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----
> ```
>
> add prefix and suffix
>
> ```
> "$(echo -e ' -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMKOQ1zYTmd\nzkRpTFq4xu\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----
> ```
>
> ')"
>
> copy-paste it to the Travis interface

It works for me :)